# How to launch a subprocess in a new terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Hello I am a beginner & sorry for my bad English.
My question is how to launch a sub process in a new terminal?

For the moment I have launched a process `Loop.py` in a new terminal with a `subprocess` function:

`Lo = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'python3', '/address/Loop.py'])`

but it’s not quit the same thing, I don't have access to the script `Loop.py` from the main script.

Thank you.

**Update:**

the main script is `Main.py`:

```
import subprocess, signal, os, time

Li = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal'])
Lo = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '/address/Loop.py'])
time.sleep(0.1)
Qd = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '/adress/Qdial.py'])

if Qd.wait() != None:
    Lo.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    Li.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)
```

The `Qdial.py`is describe here:
[Qdial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997694/problem-to-reload-a-loop-with-qdial-signal-subprocess)

The `Loop.py` is :

```
import time, signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Exit!')
    exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

def loop():
    with open('/addres/Data.py', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        A1 = lines[0]
        A1 = float(A1[4:-1])
    print('A1 = ', A1)

while True:
    loop()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

and the `Data.py` is a bunch of data, here I use just one:

```
A1 = 10
```

Comment: What do you mean by "access to the script `Loop.py` from the main script" and why do you need a new terminal? The scripted should be "accessible" via the intermediate terminal. The obvious fix for what I *guess* you want seems to be not to use a new terminal.

Comment: What do you have access to?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi As I am trying to build a GUI this will be the only terminal I will launch (if it's possible), so I can't access via another terminal there is none.
As I understand it the Lo subprocess launch the terminal and the script, but the script it self is not a subprocess.
For exemple as i send `Lo.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` in the main script it has no effect on `Loop.py`.
@psarka For the time being not so much, I don't know how to close this terminal (still a beginner)...

Comment: "As I am trying to build a GUI this will be the only terminal I will launch (if it's possible), so I can't access via another terminal there is none." But why start a terminal in the first place? Why not use `Lo = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '/address/Loop.py'])`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have tried it seems to run but nothing on the terminal...sad emoji, and I need to see what is done... Should I edit the post in order to be more complete?